# Removing side panel from dishwasher for part replacement - general advice

Tags: repair, dishwasher

I am trying to replace a part (the dish rack holder) in an old Candy dishwasher (CDW 250). I have the replacement part, but it seems that replacing it will require removing the left panel. Unfortunately, I can't find an appropriate service manual or any information on disassembling the panel. It is a metal panel which has a lip at the top, back and front. It has four screws which are visible without removing any other parts, two at the front and two at the back. Removing these loosens the panel slightly, but it is clearly held in elsewhere, possibly on top. The top of the dishwasher is just a piece of plastic which can be pulled off, so there may be more screws there.

I was wondering if there are any standard ways such a panel would be held in, places I should look for screws, and ways I should try to pull it off once loose. I assume that the standard stages for dismantling the machine would be to remove the plastic parts, then the metal panels, but maybe I'm missing something.

I've had the machine for almost 20 years and it works fine apart from the drawer holder, so I'd like to be able to fix this without damaging the machine.

Comment: Maybe a picture would help us.

Comment: Sometimes you need to remove the top surface to release the side panel.. But looking at it usually gives one enough information as to how it comes apart. The real problem is getting it back together without having bits left over, washers, screws etc.

Comment: https://elektrotanya.com/candy_cdw250.pdf/download.html#dl - I did the captcha and DL the PDF, it's legit.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I wasn't sure if that was some malware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General advice: you need the **service manual** that has exploded diagrams of every replaceable part (which is what [this is](https://elektrotanya.com/candy_cdw250.pdf/download.html#dl)), not the *user's* or the *installer's*.